# DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP error in mysql while alter the table

Tags: mysql

I'm getting error while executing any query in mysql even table is empty.

```
ALTER TABLE test_table ALTER COLUMN CREATED_DATE SET DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

ALTER TABLE test_table ADD COLUMN CREATED_DATE_temp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

error is :

> Category  Timestamp   Duration    Message Line    Position Error  01-06-2018
>   10:35:57  0:00:00.000 MySQL Database Error: You have an error in your
>   SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use near 'DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'
>   at line 1 9   0

Any help please?

Comment: You intention is to modify column `CREATED_DATE` by adding `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as a default value?

Answer (score 3):

You need to follow correct syntax for add/modify columns

```
ALTER TABLE `test_table` CHANGE `CREATED_DATE` `CREATED_DATE` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NULL; 
ALTER TABLE `test_table` ADD COLUMN `CREATED_DATE_temp` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NULL;
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6d34a)

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can just run the following command:

ALTER TABLE test_table ADD COLUMN CREATED_DATE_temp timestamp DEFAULT now();

Comment: i got this error: Category Timestamp Duration Message Line Position
Error 01-06-2018 11:34:37 0:00:00.000 MySQL Database Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'now()' at line 1 7 0

so i used the suggestion given in below answer

Answer (score 0):

Try like below query with `TIMESTAMP`:

It is now possible to achieve this with `DATETIME` fields since `MySQL 5.6.5`
But you can do it with `TIMESTAMP`

```
ALTER TABLE `test_table` ADD COLUMN `CREATED_DATE_temp` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```